# SQL SERVER – syspolicy_purge_history job failing step: Erase Phantom System Health Records

Tags: sql-server-2012

The Erase Phantom System Health Records step failing after upgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012. Please find the below error and advise.

> Executed as user: abc\abc
> A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'import-module SQLPS  -DisableNameChecking'.
>
> Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\Sqlps.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system.
>
> Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.  File C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\Sqlps.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.  '.  Process Exit Code
> -1.  The step failed.

Comment: Hello Noor and welcome to Stack Overflow. I am wondering if you've analyzed the error message and tried anything yourself? If so, do not hesitate to add what you tried to your question ([edit] your question to do so) and what the result if your tries was. Reading the second paragraph tells you that execution of scripts is disabled on the system. I would suggest enabling execution of scripts to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

So lved the issue after turnon Script Execution and execution policy to Allow all scripts.

Run->gpedit.msc
Computer Configuration
 -->Windows administrative templates->Windows Components-> Windows Powershell-> turnon Script Execution and Allow all scripts(Execution Policy)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on my  SQL server 2012  and finally were able to fix it. There are a lot of step involved in this fix  which I have documented at below link.

Hope this works for you.

http://accidentalsqldba.blogspot.com/2019/12/syspolicypurgehistory-sql-agent-job-is.html